# Implementation of AssignWithSeed?

Tags: instructions, owner, systemprogram

I cant seem to understand how to change the ownership of a system owned account. How do I pass in new owner to the instruction?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the owner of an account, you're supposed to use the `Assign` instruction on the system program, which requires a signature from the account.

There may be a misunderstanding about what account ownership means in Solana.  The owner of an account is meant to be a program, which has the right to make changes the account.

For example, a token account is owned by the token program, and the token program is allowed to change the data in the account.  You can read more about it at https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/accounts#ownership-and-assignment-to-programs

Comment: Is Assign also used when the account was created with seed? I thought that's what AssignWithSeed was for. Also I just want nobody to be able to reassign ownership later as I understand a systemProgram owned account can change ownership

Comment: `CreateAccount` = `Allocate` + `Assign`, so `CreateAccountWithSeed` = `AllocateWithSeed` + `AssignWithSeed`. For the most part though, you shouldn't be using any of the `*WithSeed` instructions, and rather use Program-Derived Addresses for programs.  You'll need to clarify more in your question what you're trying to do.

Comment: You're right as to PDA being a perfect solution the only thing is the program wouldn't execute if the signer/payer was one of the accounts used to generate the pda so I figured this would work too but I think I'm just gonna create a third account for one time use to pay for the PDA tx. Then maybe make a request on GitHub for the team to allow this in the future

Comment: Your on-chain program can encode those rules, that's the whole power of PDAs! So for example, in order to create a PDA whose seed is the user, your program can require that the user signs the transaction.

Comment: Yeah the only reason I went the Createwithseed route was as a workaround that would save me time but it's proven to be more work lol Ill just use a PDA